# Background task visible in lifecycle events during debug but doesnt run automatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, uwp, background-task

### Issue

I want to use a background task to show toast notification in windows phone 8.1. I followed this article to add the background task [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx). The problem is that the background task never runs. Its runs only when I call it from lifecycle events when In debug mode.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/a/devicebee.com/file/d/0B2oNtA2ksz2FbnRkSHdfYUVEX2s/edit?usp=sharing).. this screenshot shows when its in debug mode. the code for registering is also shown in the screenshot. I have also made it toast capable, and this is what I did in the declaration [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2oNtA2ksz2FUTRTNGt6VVZCdUk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: and this is what I did in the background task class. [screenshot for background task class](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2oNtA2ksz2FZ1FBU0ZrX2pTNVU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I found the problem. Its with the BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync(); .. which Is returning me denied, i.e. its not allowing the application to run the background task. any help –

Comment: @ZainUllah Have you declared the background task in the application manifest?

Comment: @Jogy ya I have declared, I Found that my application is not getting permission to run background task. It always returns denied when I try to get access with BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync..(Reason : too many background tasks). If I give it access manually then it works fine. I have also written some code for badge but it doesn't show on the lock screen.

Comment: @ZainUllah have you found the problem? i'm having the exact same

Answer (score 1):

this is very tricky. but i assume there might be a lot of other background tasks running at the sametime which are not allowing your task to run.
try restarting the phone and then launch this app first. that should solve it.